# Rearchitecting existing Desktop application to technology that support multiple platforms

Tags: android, .net, ios, asp.net-mvc

We recently confronted a challenge where we got to port an Existing Desktop (.NET 3.5) application (Which communicates a WCF service and a Webservice) to the technology that can meet following:

Should support IPAD 
Should Support IPhone 
should support Android
Should Support Window Mobile
Should be on WEB based, so that can run on DT. 
Optimized in Performance. 
Cool UI.

With so many technologies available to support them all. Its become a challenge for us to finalize one upon other. So far, we are thinking about a Web based application in ASP.NET MVC-4 (As we are .NET engineers). We are open for suggestions.

Thanks for your suggestions and time you devote in helping me.

Regards
Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the MONO Project it is a open source project that aims to bring the .net framework to linux/mac os [Mono Website](http://www.mono-project.com) mobile development does come with a licensing fee in order to deploy to a device or distribute the application   tho there is also phonegap which lets you use javascript and html5 markup to create native cross platform applications for mobile platforms  [PhoneGap Website](http://phonegap.com/)